# Как расположить два layout ниже RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Всех приветствую. Подскажите пожалуйста,как расположить layouts ниже RecyclerView. В моём интерфейсе они не отображаются (frameLayout нужен для добавления фрагмента в код). Мне советовали constraintLayout,но может можно как-то обойтись без него? Заранее благодарю всех за помощь.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:contentDescription="@string/title_favourites">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/favourites_info"/>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
        android:name=".FragmentFavouriteNews"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        tools:context=".FragmentNews"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_item_news">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
        <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/list"
android:id="@+id/pagecontainer"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_below="@id/pagecontainer"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:orientation="vertical">
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/save"
android:text="@string/save_favourites"/>
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/load"
android:text="@string/load_favourites"/>
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/clear"
android:text="@string/clear_favourites"/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Чем RelativeLayout не подошел? Внешний LinerLayout сделайте тогда.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду вместо framelayout?

Comment: RelativeLayout подойдет. Все зависит от макета который вы хотите получить. Если RecycleView на весь экран а внизу кнопки, то сделайте контейнер с кнопками android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" а RecycleView (растяните на весь экран) android:layout_above со ссылкой на контейнер с кнопками.

Comment: Я как-то делал так,но у меня ниже framelayout есть ещё второй layout и вот он,вроде,выходил за экран.

Comment: нужно android:layout_below="@id/list" добавить в внутри блока <LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

Слава Богу благодаря @Style-7 и @Hellraiser у меня всё получилось. Вот мой xml код (если его можно улучшить,можете предложить идею).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:contentDescription="@string/title_favourites">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/favourites_info"/>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
        android:name=".FragmentFavouriteNews"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        tools:context=".FragmentNews"
        android:layout_above="@id/pagecontainer"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_item_news">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
        <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/pagecontainer"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_below="@id/list"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:orientation="vertical">
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/save"
android:text="@string/save_favourites"/>
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/load"
android:text="@string/load_favourites"/>
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/clear"
android:text="@string/clear_favourites"/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Благослови всех вас Бог за помощь. Теперь,вроде,всё работает как надо.

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Comment: @aleksandr barakin Я написал это как ответ,т.к мне помогли советы людей,поэтому я и оформил это как ответ.

Comment: вопросов внутри ответов вообще-то быть не должно. например, можете задать их отдельно **по одному**, упомянув и данный вопрос при необходимости.

Comment: Уговорили. Задал вопрос на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1562759/%d0%a2%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81-recyclerview-%d0%b2-xml.

Comment: Как оказалось,вопрос полностью не решился. Почему-то в некоторых случаях linearlayout идёт после списка,а мне надо,чтобы он шёл после framelayout. Если использовать android:layout_below="id/list",то кнопки выходят за экран.

Comment: В общем у кого есть идеи,пишите в телегу (t.me/sashablr_1994).